# hosting gh-pages on custom domain, white empty page

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

im new to coding and need some help.
 I made a react project (using create-react-app), and the website has been running on my gh-pages branch

(heres my repo: https://github.com/simchaleh/shivisihashem.git)

ive been trying to host the gh-pages project on a custom domain instead.
my react project looks great when its hosted on gh-pages, but when i try to connect it to my custom domain, all i get is a solid white screen.

heres a screen pic of my dns settings on custom domain. (u can also see that gh-pages says its hosting on my domain):
[dns settings and gh-pages/settings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbbM4.png)

I have a CNAME file in gh-pages branch, with one line, where i put:
shivisihashem.com

does anyone have any ideas why im just getting a blank white screen on my custom domain?

thanks!

Answer (score 8):

i just got an answer from github staff. it solved my issue.
heres the answer if anyone else has this same issue:

> The file you need to edit is here:
>
> https://github.com/simchaleh/shivisihashem/blob/gh-pages/index.html
>
> Currently, these two sections have errors:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
> src="/ShivisiHashem/static/js/main.7cdb5ccf.js"></script>
> 
> <link href="/ShivisiHashem/static/css/main.ff643f95.css"
> rel="stylesheet">
```

> You should be able to resolve the issue by replacing them with these:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
> src="/static/js/main.7cdb5ccf.js"></script>
> 
> <link href="/static/css/main.ff643f95.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

> I hope that helps! Let us know if you have any other issues.

Comment: I was able to automate this by removing the "/repo_name" from the end of the `homepage: ...` property in my package.json

Comment: Hey, I tried this, but I have assets. With this solution, the css and js files get included, but the same error occurs for all assets too! Is there any way to automate this? We can't possibly have to edit the chunk files by replacing all the occurrences of repo-name

Comment: Thanks it worked for me and as @Nigh7Sh4de said you can save a lot by just changing the homepage uri in package.json by removing the repo-name from the end.

Answer (score 2):

Simcha's solution worked for me temporarily. Every time I was deploying to Github pages, the index.html file was automatically reverted back to `"/theNameOfMyApp/static/...`. So I managed to get rid of this problem, by removing the `"/theNameOfMyApp"` part from the `homepage: ...` in package.json. So in package.json there I have: `"homepage": "http://themitsoss.github.io"`.

Comment: It redirects to 404 for me. The only solution working for me is to remove the repo name from index.html

Comment: What if I have a repo hosted at "username.github.io"?

Answer (score 0):

Had this same problem. I believe this issue is caused when you use the PUBLIC_URL environment variable, like so:

`%PUBLIC_URL%/main.css`

which works for the github.io site but causes path problems in the custom domain, which adds the variable in front of the path like in Simcha's example. So, we need to manually remove every instance of the this variable (process.env.PUBLIC_URL) each time we build for gh-pages.

Comment: Should we remove "process.env.PUBLIC_URL". If so what should it be replaced with?