# Using GitHub pages, blank white screen

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I'm trying to make a react project on github pages using [username].github.io. but when I go on the link, it just returns a white screen without any error messages. This also happens when I use a custom domain name.

However, it works when I run it locally and also when I use gh-pages instead of a user repo.

I used https://medium.freecodecamp.org/surge-vs-github-pages-deploying-a-create-react-app-project-c0ecbf317089 to upload all my files into github since I created the repo at the end after I finished, but I tweaked it a little to work without gh-pages.

I also referred to this answer: [hosting gh-pages on custom domain, white empty page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44484377/hosting-gh-pages-on-custom-domain-white-empty-page) but it didn't do anything for me.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Change **`BrowserRouter`** to **`HashRouter`** as follow

**Before:**

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**After:**

```
import { HashRouter } from "react-router-dom"

ReactDOM.render(
    <HashRouter><App /></HashRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Do you know why BrowserRouter is not working with gh-pages?

Comment: https://medium.com/@Dragonza/react-router-problem-with-gh-pages-c93a5e243819 check this article @Mudassar045

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're getting an error on the console. You might need to switch from BroswerRouter to HashRouter, because gh-pages doesn't work well with the former.

Comment: I've changed it to HashRouter but I still have a blank screen. When I use inspect element on it, it has 4 error messages that says "Failed to load resource: the server responded defaultmin.css with a status of 404 (Not Found)", and another one that has a status of "400 (Bad Request)". I'm not sure why though.

Comment: Are you using redirects? It might be failing. I had that problem and I debugged it using logs at each point of the redirect (renders, component mounts and component updates)

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late to this discussion, but I ran into this same issue and I found a solution that was not listed here.

Here is the solution I found: https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages/issues/3#issuecomment-399787987

The issue this user was having was related to how GitHub serves your react build from GitHub Pages. GitHub pages serves your react build from a folder names after your repository directory instead of from the root server directory "/". Hopefully this link will help someone else out in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Using react router in my create-react-app i had this same issue. What solved it for me was adding this line to the router.

`<Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>`