# How can I deploy my React app on gh-pages (github pages)?

Tags: reactjs, build, github-pages

I am trying to deploy my react app using gh-pages, and after upload it I found white page. I tried many solutions but nothing work.

this is the url :

https://mosherad.github.io/spreago-react/

and here is the json file

```
{
  "name": "spreago",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.3",
    "@hapi/hawk": "^7.1.2",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.8.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "gh-pages": "^2.2.0",
    "graphql": "^14.5.8",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "lodash.flowright": "^3.5.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.8.0",
    "react-material-ui-form-validator": "^2.0.9",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
    "serve": "^11.3.0",
    "yarn": "^1.21.1",
    "yarn-install": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "homepage": "https://mosherad.github.io/spreago-react/",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: that's help me :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47986545/using-github-pages-blank-white-screen